Initialized variable in component file not binding to HTML file, shows no error or value
My code in parent component initiates a pop up window using MatDailog and passes value to constructor in child component.
Code in Parent Component-
enter image description here

`   this.dialog.open(ChildComponent, {
    disableClose: false,
    width: '700px',
    data: {
        responseDetails: this.dataSourceTable,
        changeStatus: 'Open',
        header : this.headerName,
        loader : true,
    }
    
}
);`


Popup opens up and no data is visible but html shows no data. a variable is initialized in child component which is also not visible on UI.
code in Child component-

headingItem : string = "Blank Heading Item";

Code in constructor which initializes headingItem again:

`  constructor( 
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data: any,public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ChildComponent>)
    {
            this.dataSource = data.responseDetails;
            this.headingItem = data.header;
            console.log("constructor data :",this.dataSource,this.headingItem);
     }`


Code in HTML-

<h2>{{headingItem}}</h2>
<h3>static heading</h3>


Screenshot of result:
enter image description here
static heading is visible but "headingItem" is not visible , console shows no Error , and upon further investigation of ng Life cycle hooks, none of the life cycle hooks are called when we call fmea-Versioning component not even ngOnInit which is already a part of implementation. Only when we exit the pop up ngOnDestroy is called.

Please do not share code as screenshot, I've analyzed your code and I don't think that I don't think that the error lies in the snippet that you shared, could you please share enough code so that I can reproduce the error, or share a StackBlitz where you managed to reproduce the error.
